# Replicate data from one list to another list sharepoint

Tags: list

I have a list A with columns Emp ID, First name & last name and list B wih column name Emp ID, First name, last name , phone number and address.

I want functionality such that when i enter item in List A and save same data should get copied in 3 columns of list B.
Can someone help me with the approach. Thnks

Answer (score 1):

You can automate this process in two ways

1. Creating a SharePoint Designer Workflow
2. Creating an event receiver

Both has advantages and disadvantages. Designer workflow is simple and easy to develop. It doesn't require any kind of deployment. It can be developed using SharePoint Designer. The person who is developing doesn't require any programming background

To create a workflow follow below steps

1. Open SharePoint designer and open the site which has the lists
2. From left navigation click on workflows
3. From Ribbon Create a new list workflow for list A
4. Make the workflow to start automatically on item create and item update
5. Workflow logic

   - Check if current item - Emp ID exists in list B
   - if not exists, then create new item in list B using current item values
   - if exists, then update list B item which has Emp ID = Current Item: Emp ID

Comment: How to also sync on deletion. A solution could be to match ID's of both lists and delete items from child list