# Get IDs of all List Items in a list and compare them to another List to sync deleted Items in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, designer-workflow, flow

Using ***SharePoint Designer workflow*** or ***Flow*** how can I get IDs of all list items in a List and compare them to IDs of list items in another List so that we can *sync* the deleted items

I am able to sync *Creation* and *Updation* via workflow given here: [Replicate data from one list to another list sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128596/replicate-data-from-one-list-to-another-list-sharepoint)

But how do I also sync *Deletion*?

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow steps:**

1.I have two lists "Test123" and "Backup-Test123" from different sites

[image]

2.Create a MS Flow to sync delete same items

a. Add the **Recurrence** Trigger

b. Add first "**Get itmes**" Action to get all items from "Test123" list

c. Add second "**Get itmes**" Action to get all items from "Backup-Test123" list

d. Add the **Condition**: Set the corresponding conditions according to the content of your lists. For example: In my test,

- Title (Get item2) is equal to Title (Get item)
- Colors Value (Get item2) is equal to Colors Value (Get item)
- Status Value (Get item2) is equal to Status Value (Get item)

e. Then, in the "**if yes**" sction:

- Add first "Delete itmes" Action to delete same item form "Test123" list. In my test, Id is ***ID from "Get items" Action***
- Add second "Delete itmes" Action to delete same items form "Backup-Test123" list. In my test, ***Id is ID from "Get items 2" Action***

[image]

3.Save and Test Flow

4.Navigate to these two lists, you will find that same items have been deleted.

[image]